# How to normalize an array by the sum of the array in Hive?

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table like this:

```
id  | value_array
1   | [1, 2, 3, 4]
2   | [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

I wish to normalize the value_array by the sum of the array so that I can get the following result:

```
id  | value_array
1   | [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
2   | [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2]
```

I don't know how to write the SQL to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode array, calculate sum(), divide each element, then collect array again. Like this (not tested):

```
with your_data as (--use your table instead of this
select stack (2,
1,array(1, 2, 3, 4),
2,array(1, 2, 1, 1)
) as (id,value_array)
)

select id, collect_list(v/array_sum) as result_array
from
(
select id, sum(v) over(partition by id) as array_sum, v, pos
  from your_data s
       lateral view posexplode(s.value_array) a as pos, v
distribute by id sort by pos --preserve original array order
)s
group by id
;
```